# ROS Answers SE migration: OpenNI 2.0

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is anyone working on upgrading to OpenNI 2.0?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56951/openni-2.0/) by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3838 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on 2013-04-08**:
Hey! I'd like to update this question, as I'm also interested if working with Openni 2.0 and ROS will be soon possible?

**Comment by [fsotosan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4542/fsotosan/) on 2013-05-21**:
I'm also interested on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Under hydro, you can use the following:

- openni2_camera and openni2_launch drivers support Primesense/Asus devices.
- freenect_stack drivers support Kinect

Both packages end up using rgbd_launch for shared functionality (such as loading image_proc and depth_proc nodelets), so it is somewhat easier to switch between the two drivers as they support similar parameters and topic names.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[openni2_camera](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni2_camera) and [openni2_launch](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni2_launch) have been released. Currently they are only available on the shadow-fixed repository. The next sync should make them available on the public repo as well.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-09-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everybody, as this is "the thread" for OpenNI 2, I would like to let you know of a procedure to make it work with Ubuntu and kinects. Here is the procedure :

1. Install Ubuntu 12.10 (the version 13.04 doesn't work with kinects)
2. sudo apt-get install freenect
3. Download and install OpenNI 2.2 :

   cd OpenNI-2.2/
   sudo ./install.h
4. Download and install NITE 2.2 :

   cd Nite-2.2/
   sudo ./install.h
5. Download Driver FreenectDriver

   https://github.com/piedar/OpenNI2-FreenectDriver
6. Build driver

   ./waf configure build
7. Copy .so files (build/libFreenectDriver.so ), and paste it in :

   OpenNI-2.2/Redist/OpenNI2/Drivers
   OpenNI-2.2/Samples/Bin/OpenNI2/Drivers
   Nite-2.2/Samples/Bin/OpenNI2/Drivers

Have a good day everybody !

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-09-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-09-15**:
Did the driver and launchers in the ROS freenect stack (https://github.com/ros-drivers/freenect_stack) not work for you?

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-09-15**:
Good question. in fact, we didn't try/search, as OpenNI 2 was not (yet) supported in ROS, we tried to see if it was possible to have OpenNI 2.2 working with kinect and Ubuntu, without ROS. But it's good to see some packages exist !